# Sum of all 4 digit numbers formed using 6 numbers

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> Find the sum of all four digit numbers (without repetition of digits) formed using the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$

I have tried this problem and my answer is
$\frac{5!}{2!}\times (1+2+3+4+5+6)\times (10^3+10^2+10+1)=1399860$

Am i right?

Comment: Two issues: (a) ${}_5P_3=5!/2!$ not $5!/3!$, and (b) $4$-digits means up to $10^3$ not $10^4$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, let me check in another way

- Average digit $= 3.5$
- Average number giving place value $=3.5(1111)$
- Number of permutations $=^6P_4 = 360$
- Multiplying out, $3.5\cdot1111\cdot360 = 1399860\;\, \boxed{OK}$

**PS**

But while your answer is correct, the expression you have written certainly doesn't evaluate to the answer ! Did you check what your expression evaluates to ? Can you explain your expression ?

**PPS**

OP has later on corrected the expression to match the result.

Comment: OP wrote each summand as a "polynomial in $10$," combined like terms, and factored. See my comment under OP for the issues in OP's expression.

Comment: @coiso: What is your $_5P_3$ representing ?

Comment: How many numbers have a given numeral within a given digit.

Comment: @coiso: I can't understand. How can you have a numeral within a digit. How does $5$ come in your expression ? There are $6$ digits you can use, and the *numbers* contain $4$ digits .

Comment: How many $4$-digit numbers have distinct numbers from $1,2,3,4,5,6$ used for digits and have leading digit $1$? Answer: ${}_5P_{\,3}$. What about how many such numbers have second digit $2$? Same answer. Etc.

Comment: @coiso: Ok, I understand.